# Show there is no elementary extension of $\mathbb{N}$ with an element between $0$ and 1

Tags: logic, model-theory

I have been presented with the follwing question and I want to see if the method I have used works. I have my doubts.

We recall that $M$ is an elementary extension of $N= \langle \mathbb{N}; +, ., 0, 1 \rangle$ if for a formula $\phi(x)$ and every element n of the naturals,  $\phi(n)$ is true in $N$ if and only if it is true in $M$.

My thought process is then consider the formula $\exists x[0<x$ and $1<x]$ then the negation of this is true and so must be true in the extension as well?

Is this the right approach? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It's the right approach, but you should say why $0<x$ and $1<x$ are formulas.

Comment: so i need to show that < is definable in N?

Comment: @ENAFMTH: yes, that is correct

Comment: Alternatively, if $M$ is an elementary extension of $N$, then $M$ and $N$ are elementary equivalent. Then the sentence $\neg \exists x (0 < x < 1)$, is true in $N$, and so, true in $M$. I think the formula you have isn't quite what you want, all it says is that there is something bigger than 0 and bigger than 1, but that is equivalent (in $N$) to it just being bigger than 1.